# Returning matching characters from a string array in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

Im having difficulty with something that is probably simple.
Essentially i want to return any instances of a character inside an array, my example here should provide more clarity then this explanation. One thing to note is that ill be doing this in a loop and the index wont be the same nor will the letter in question, therefore as far as im aware i cant .indexof or substring;

```
$array = "asdfsdgfdshghfdsf"
$array -match "d"
```

returns: True

What i would like it to return: ddd

Abit like grep in bash

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `-replace` operator to remove anything that *isn't* a `d`:

```
PS ~> $string = "asdfsdgfdshghfdsf"
PS ~> $string -replace '[^d]'
dddd
```

Note that all string operators in PowerShell are case-**in**sensitive by default, use `-creplace` for case-sensitive replacement:

```
PS ~> $string = "abcdABCD"
PS ~> $string -replace '[^d]'
dD
PS ~> $string -creplace '[^d]'
d
```

You can generate the negative character class pattern from a string like this:

```
# define a string with all the characters
$allowedCharacters = 'abc'

# generate a regex pattern of the form `[^<char1><char2><char3>...]`
$pattern = '[^{0}]' -f $allowedCharacters.ToCharArray().ForEach({[regex]::Escape("$_")})
```

Then use with `-replace` (or `-creplace`) like before:

```
PS ~> 'abcdefgabcdefg' -replace $pattern
abcabc
```

Answer (score 1):

Using select-string -allmatches, the matches object array would contain all the matches.  The -join is converting matches to strings.

```
$array = 'asdfsdgfdshghfdsf'
-join ($array | select-string d -AllMatches | % matches)

dddd
```